# BIND: How to refer requests to other DNS servers in different predefined networks

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, linux-networking, local-area-network

Let's say I have two independent networks `net1.local` and `net2.local` each of which is connected to a bigger network `local` through a router.

Each of 3 networks have their own independent DNS server.
Now, a host in `net1.local` tries to resolve a name from `net2.local`. Something like this:

```
nslookup host1.net2.local
```

The DNS server located in `net1.local` does not know anything about `net2.local` hosts, and the DNS server located in the bigger network only knows the top domain names as it contains these records:

```
net1       IN A      192.168.10.1
net2       IN A      192.168.20.1
```

What would be the best practice to configure DNS servers to achieve this??

Answer (score 3):

DNS is designed to be a tree, where everything can be found by starting at the top and following pointers down. It's perfectly possible to set up such a tree of your own on your isolated network. If you set things up this way, everything will work normally, documentation will make sense and you will have the least amount of unpleasant surprises.

From you question, it sounds that rather than a tree you're trying to set up a number (two, in this case) of isolated islands with lines of communication between them that you define from outside DNS (that is, in the BIND configuration). It may be possible to do that, but it's sure is going to be a lot harder and a lot more work than setting up a private tree. Also there will be no documentation relating to your solution, and every time you want help you'll have to explain everything you've done from scratch.

So set up a tree and have your top-level domain simply delegate to the other two domains.

Also, don't use the name `.local`. It's reserved for multicast DNS, as per RFC 6762 section 3. You may think that you're not using mDNS, but if there are devices running Android, iOS, Linux or OSX on your network, you are, you just don't know it. Pick another name, even if your DNS tree is totally isolated from the rest of the world.